# Macro to change color of map (States)

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I need help coding this VBA for a work project. I have a map with all the shapes (States) named and I have column U2:U52 with the the State abbreviations and column V2:V52 with the data.  I need a macro to run through an "If Then" statement to change the colors and Loop through each State (line of data) based on the data entered.

```
Sub map1()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim ShapeName As String
Dim SHP As Shape

ShapeName = "AL"

Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("V2")
Set SHP = Rng.Parent.Shapes(ShapeName)


If Rng.Value <= 1.6 Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'Red

End If

If Rng.Value > 1.6 And Rng.Value < 2.4 Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0) 'Green

End If

If Rng.Value >= 2.4 Then
SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0) 'yellow

End If

End Sub
```

The way its written is for just one shape, how do I change it to run all states without coding it 52 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple loop that should work.

```
Sub map1()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim ShapeName As String
Dim SHP As Shape

For i = 2 to 52

    ShapeName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("U" & i).Value

    Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("V" & i)
    Set SHP = Rng.Parent.Shapes(ShapeName)

    If Rng.Value <= 1.6 Then
        SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'Red
    ElseIf Rng.Value > 1.6 And Rng.Value < 2.4 Then
        SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0) 'Green
    ElseIf Rng.Value >= 2.4 Then
        SHP.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0) 'yellow
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```